# RoR select, retain item value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am listing items using "select"

on selecting an item-3 from the list iam reloading the page, same for all the items.

When page reloads, select takes to item-1 again.

I want to retain item-3 even after page reload.

Answer (score 0):

it's normal if you're reloading the page during, for example, a *new* action. for *edit* actions it will load the selected item.

so, if you want to reload the page preserving data/selections, you should create a specific action that takes params[] arguments and load them in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Use `select()` as follows:

```
<%= 
    select(
      "booking", 
      "airline",  
      @airlines.collect {|a| [ a.name, a.code ] }, 
      { :include_blank => true }
    ) 
%>
```

This will retain the value if the form submits and is returned or the page is refreshed.

The documentation doesn't mention the issue but can be found here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select